# Why does the Task.ContinueWith fail to execute in this Unit Test?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, task-parallel-library

I have come across a problem with a unit test that failed because a TPL Task never executed its `ContinueWith(x, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())`.

The problem turned out to be because a Winforms UI Control was accidentally being created before the Task was started.

Here is an example that reproduces it.  You will see that if you run the test as-is, it passes.  If you run the test with the Form line uncommented, it fails.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Create new sync context for unit test
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

        var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        var doer = new DoSomethinger();

        //Uncommenting this line causes the ContinueWith part of the Task
        //below never to execute.
        //var f = new Form();

        doer.DoSomethingAsync(() => waitHandle.Set());

        Assert.IsTrue(waitHandle.WaitOne(10000), "Wait timeout exceeded.");
    }
}


public class DoSomethinger
{
    public void DoSomethingAsync(Action onCompleted)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (onCompleted != null)
                onCompleted();

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

**Can anyone explain why this is the case?**

I thought it might have been because the *wrong* `SynchronizationContext` is used, but actually, the `ContinueWith` *never* executes at all!  And besides, in this unit test, whether or not it is the correct `SynchronizationContext` is irrelevant because as long as the `waitHandle.set()` is called on any thread, the test should pass.

Comment: Does an exception occur?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Stupid question - you did try with the `var f = new Form();` UNcommented? I an MsTest, VS2013u4, Win8.1, Net 4.5.1

Comment: @OffHeGoes Sorry I overlooked that. Writing an answer now :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, no exception.  If I remove the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, it passes too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I overlooked the comments section in your code, Indeed that fails when uncommenting the `var f = new Form();`

Reason is subtle, `Control` class will automatically overwrite the synchronization context to `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` if it sees that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` or its is of type `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext`.

As soon as Control class overwrite the `SynchronizationContext.Current` with `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, all the calls to `Send` and `Post` expects the windows message loop to be running in order to work. That's not going to happen till you created the `Handle` and you run a message loop.

Relevant part of the problematic code:

```
internal Control(bool autoInstallSyncContext)
{
    ...
    if (autoInstallSyncContext)
    {
       //This overwrites your SynchronizationContext
        WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded();
    }
}
```

You can refer the source of `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded` [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,06282f9a00b38e67,references).

If you want to overwrite the `SynchronizationContext`, you need your custom implementation of `SynchronizationContext` to make it work.

Workaround:

```
internal class MyContext : SynchronizationContext
{

}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Create new sync context for unit test
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new MyContext());

    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    var doer = new DoSomethinger();
    var f = new Form();

    doer.DoSomethingAsync(() => waitHandle.Set());

    Assert.IsTrue(waitHandle.WaitOne(10000), "Wait timeout exceeded.");
}
```

Above code works as expected :)

Alternatively you could set `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall` to `false`, that will prevent automatic overwriting of the synchronization context mentioned above.(Thanks for OP @OffHeGoes for mentioning this in comments)

Comment: Ah, I think I know what I did wrong - I was checking `TaskScheduler.Current` when trying to debug the problem - I should have been checking `SynchronizationContext.Current`!

Comment: That's really useful to know.  I've just looked at the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded()` and can see that it checks for `typeof(SynchronizationContext)`.

Comment: Also noticed that you can do this to stop it too: `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false;`

Answer (score 4):

With the line commented out, your `SynchronizationContext` is the default one you created. This will cause  `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchrozisationContext()` to use the default scheduler, which will run the continuation on the thread pool.

Once you create a Winforms object like your Form, the current `SynchronizationContext` becomes a [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx), which in turn will return a scheduler that depends on the WinForms message pump to schedule the continuation.

Since there is no WinForms pump in a unit test, the continuation never gets run.

Comment: Thanks - I was checking `TaskScheduler.Current` when trying to debug the problem - I should have been checking `SynchronizationContext.Current`.