# Why does this async call not complete?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, deadlock

Why does the following code not work (meaning it never reaches the MessageBox saying that it is done)?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async Task SomeTask1()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => await SomeTask2());
    }

    async Task SomeTask2()
    {
       var tb = new Button();          
       await Task.Delay(100);            
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await SomeTask1();
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
}
```

This is very simplified repro code from actual code found in a real system. I am aware that I can resolve this by

- Removing Task.Run from SomeTask1 and just await-ing SomeTask2 directly, or
- Removing the line "var tb = new Button()" from SomeTask2, or
- Invoking the line "var tb = new Button()" in SomeTask2

However, I am interested in WHY this does not work, not how to fix it. Is it because the "new Button()" line messes up the sync context?

Comment: Sorry, there is no connection between them. The click handler is for an unrelated button.

Comment: Answer is [subtle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191518/why-does-the-task-continuewith-fail-to-execute-in-this-unit-test). Refer the linked answer. I explained why that happens. I'm not sure whether closing this as duplicate is right decision.

Comment: @RoyiNamir You're missing the meat of the question. Add `new Button` and see.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's a very nice find.

Comment: @I3arnon Thanks! I'm glad that you found it interesting.